# Prove that $|z| \le |z-1|+1$ and $|z-1| \le |z|+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Prove that for any $ z \in \mathbb{C}$:

1. $|z| \le |z-1|+1$
2. $|z-1| \le |z|+1$

I take any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $z=a+bi$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. I received:

1. $\sqrt{a^2 +b^2} \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2 -2a+1}+1$
2. $\sqrt{a^2+b^2 -2a+1}\le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}+1$

But I don't know how can I prove that these inequality are always true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the triangle inequality, these are immediate; recall that this states that for $x, y \in \mathbb{C}$,

$$|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|$$

For the first, set $x = z - 1$, $y = 1$.

The second is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Both follow by triangle inequality of the norm.

(1) $|z|=|(z-1)+1|\le|z-1|+1$

(2) $|z-1|\le|z|+|-1|=|z|+1$

Answer (score 3):

We do it the ugly way, to show it can be done. But the **right** way is to use the Triangle Inequality. For example, we want to show that 
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \le \sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}+1.\tag{1}$$
(Note that we did not expand yet. Why bother, unless it is useful?)

Since both sides are non-negative, Inequality (1) is equivalent to the following inequality, obtained by squaring both sides:
$$a^2+b^2\le (a-1)^2+b^2+2\sqrt{(a-1)^2 +b^2}+1.\tag{2}$$
This inequality is equivalent to 
$$2a-2\le 2\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}.$$
(Now we did expand one of the $(a-1)^2$.)

But $b^2\ge 0$, so $2\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}\le 2\sqrt{(a-1)^2}=2|a-1|$. Thus we only need to show that 
$$2(a-1)\le 2|a-1|.$$
This is obvious.

A similar manipulation takes care of the second inequality.

Comment: I think it should be $2\sqrt{(a-1)^{2}+b^{2}}\ge2\sqrt{(a-1)^{2}}$.